# Editar una celda Google Sheet API

Tags: java, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api

Nuevamente vengo con un problema con la API de Google Sheet:

Para este caso, tengo una hoja de cálculo o Spreadsheet y quiero modificar/editar una de sus celdas. La request quedaría así:

```
{updateCells={
    fields=*, 
    range={
        endColumnIndex=6, 
        endRowIndex=2, 
        sheetId=123456789, 
        startColumnIndex=5, 
        startRowIndex=1
    }, 
    rows=[{
        values=[{
            userEnteredValue={
                stringValue==D2*(1-Ficha!L6)+Ficha!L2*Ficha!L6
            }
        }]
    }], 
    start={
        columnIndex=5, 
        rowIndex=1, 
        sheetId=123456789
    }
}}
```

Si la lanzo, Google me da el siguiente error:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_cells' (oneof), oneof field 'area' is already set. Cannot set 'start'",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_cells' (oneof), oneof field 'area' is already set. Cannot set 'start'",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Intuyo que la request esta mal formada, pero no logro descubrir el error

Si alguien pudiera echarme una mano...

Gracias de antemano

Saludos

PD: Lo estoy haciendo con Java, pero viendo que la API de Google encapsula las peticiones he optado por no ponerlo

Comment: No he usado la API de la hoja de cálculo de Google pero no creo que funcione como piensas. ¿Has probado la API en cuestión usando el explorador de APIs de Google?

Comment: Tenías razón @Rubén, al probarlo en el explorador me he dado cuenta que estaba usando una request que no era la que quería. Ya he conseguido dar con la adecuada. Muchas gracias por guiarme por el buen camino ;)

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los problemas, quizás entre otros, que tiene tu request es que las propiedades no están entre comillas y tampoco estás colocando entre comillas las cadenas. Por ejemplo

```
stringValue==D2*(1-Ficha!L6)+Ficha!L2*Ficha!L6
```

debería ser

```
"stringValue"="=D2*(1-Ficha!L6)+Ficha!L2*Ficha!L6"
```

Revisa el ejemplo en https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data

Comment: Como he puesto, estoy utilizando la librería java que encapsula todas las peticiones y no tengo que preocuparme por la sintaxis. He revisado varias request que si que funcionan y el formato es el mismo, sin las comillas entre las cadenas

Comment: @MiguelGarcía pues que maravilla de librería. Deberías mencionar cual es.

Comment: Es la propia de Google. La puedes encontrar aquí: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/libraries#java